# AutoRedirect user to change password screen in django

Tags: django, redirect, django-users, django-middleware, change-password

I have a user profile model as below

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    .........
    .........
    password_changed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a `PASSWORD_EXPIRATION` setting in settings.py based on which i should redirect the user to password change screen, for example if the `password_changed` date for the user exceeds `PASSWORD_EXPIRATION` setting then redirect the user to password change screen

So for now i have three conditions to implement

```
1. If the password_changed date was empty,redirect the user to password change screen
2. If the password_changed date exists for the user and if it exceeds PASSWORD_EXPIRATION setting then redirect the user to password change screen
3. Don't let the user access other screens/urls if the password expires/without changing the passwords and redirect to password change screen
```

For the first two points i have implemented in `login` method as below

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                try:
                    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
                    # If password_changed date does not exists, redirect to password change screen
                    if not profile.password_changed:
                        auth_login(request, user)
                        return redirect('change_password')
                    # If password_changed date exists, calculate the expiry date and redirect accordingly
                    ..............
                    ..............
                    days_for_password_to_expire = int(settings.PASSWORD_EXPIREDAYS) - int(password_changed_from_now.days)
                    if days_for_password_to_expire < 0:
                        auth_login(request, user)
                        request.session['expired'] = True
                        return redirect('change_password')
```

For the third point i have implemented the middileware class as below

**middleware.py**

```
class AutoRedirect:
  def process_request(self, request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        if user:
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            if profile.password_changed:
                password_changed_from_now = timezone.now() - profile.password_changed
                days_for_password_to_expire = int(settings.PASSWORD_EXPIREDAYS) - \
                                       int(password_changed_from_now.days)
                if days_for_password_to_expire < 0:
                    return redirect('change_password')
            else:
                return redirect('change_password')
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

With the above Middleware class i was getting the error as

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

### Terminal Output

```
[18/Aug/2015 00:25:15] "GET /change_password/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Aug/2015 00:25:15] "GET /change_password/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Aug/2015 00:25:15] "GET /change_password/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Aug/2015 00:25:15] "GET /change_password/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Aug/2015 00:25:15] "GET /change_password/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
................
................
```

I understand the problem that it was facing, but how can i avoid it in the middle class logic to check whether password_changed contains data and if it expires redirect to change password screen ? so that user's can't access any url on the site ?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, but there is one more check to do: if user is already on password change screen, you shouldn't redirect him. You can simply resolve URL from request:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
```

and compare if current_url matches 'change_password'.

It's also good practice to inform user why he should change his password. You can use [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) for that.

And there is one more mistake on that line:

```
            if days_for_password_to_expire < 0 or not profile.password_changed:
```

second condition will be always false because you're checking it above.

Comment: Also you should cache your check to avoid unnecessary hitting database each time user loads page. Simply copy `password_changed` into session and don't hit database when it's there.

Comment: Can you rewrite my middle ware class with the following changes ?

Comment: yep i was using messages actually but i removed them in the above code just to explain straight forward

Comment: Why should I do that? The point of this site is helping, not doing it for you. If you don't understand something in my answer, ask specific question, I will try to be more precise.

Comment: yep i know, this site means to help and not coding for others, in the above suggestions, you have mentioned this line `if days_for_password_to_expire < 0 or not profile.password_changed`  as mistake and yeah but i need to check whether passwod_changed has data and if not redirect then how should i handle this situation ?

Comment: You're checking it also above in code in line `if profile.password_changed:`, if that condition fails, you should also redirect user to password change form.

Comment: yes i need to redirect the user to password change screen in two conditions 1. if the password_changed date was null 2. If password_changed date exists and exceeds expire date, actually i din't get your solution regarding this condition, where am i wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87245/discussion-between-gwynbleidd-and-shiva-krishna).

Comment: even though i have added else block and checking the url condition i was getting same`This webpage has a redirect loop`